# ¿Para qué sirve Self y This en PHP?

Tags: php, poo

quería saber el uso de estos dos y sus diferencias. He visto que tienen un uso parecido, pero lo que he visto no explican realmente cuál es mejor usar y por qué.

Comment: `self` hace referencia a la clase para así mandar llamar funciones estáticas. `this` hace referencia a un objeto ya instanciado para mandar llamar funciones de cualquier otro tipo.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**self:**

Hace referencia a la clase actual y generalmente lo usarías cuando no se genera una instancia de la misma, como cuando usas métodos estáticos:

```
class prueba{

 static function funcionDePrueba($chango) {
    return 'HOLA ' . $chango .'!';
 }

 static function saludar($chango){
    echo self::funcionDePrueba($chango);
 }
}

prueba::saludar('Astaroth'); //la función saludar imprime "HOLA Astaroth!" que es el regreso de funcionDePrueba
```

**this:**

Ahora, con `this` haces referencia al objeto actual. Esto es una clase que si tiene instancia:

```
class prueba{

 private function funcionDePrueba($chango) {
    return 'HOLA ' . $chango .'!';
 }

 static function saludar($chango){
    echo $this->funcionDePrueba($chango);
 }
}

(new prueba)->saludar('Astaroth'); //la función saludar imprime "HOLA Astaroth!" que es el regreso de funcionDePrueba
```

Debes considerar que NO se puede hacer referencia a métodos estáticos usando `this` pero a métodos públicos, privados y protegidos.

Comment: Gracias, me quedó claro.

Comment: Vale, no olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta en caso de haberlo sido para cerrar el ciclo.

Comment: Muy claro muchas gracias