# error al llamar a una funcion estatica publica desde otra clase php

Tags: php, jwt

mi clase trata de la creacion de json web token y tengo una funcion publica estatica donde al llamarle desde otra clase se debe ingresar como parametro el tiempo de validez del token pero me sale el siguiente error: `Error grave: error no detectado: usando $ esto cuando no está en el contexto del objeto en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \...`.

token.php:

```
<?php
  class token{
    public $tiempo_caducidad;

    public static function tiempo_caducidad($tiempo_caducidad){
      $this->tiempo_caducidad = $tiempo_caducidad;
    }
  }
?>
```

registrar_persona.php

```
<?php
  require(token.php);

  class registrar_persona{
     function principal(){
       token::tiempo_caducidad(60*60);
     }
  }
  $clase_registrar_persona = new registrar_persona();
  $clase_registrar_persona->principal();
?>
```

Comment: revisar documentacion https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: ya le cambie de `private $tiempo_caducidad` a `public $tiempo_caducidad` y sigue saliendo el mismo error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que tienes un problema de sintaxis que se corrige facil, solo debes agregar la palabra reservada `static` antes del modificador de acceso de la clase `token`; te coloco el código y posteriormente explico mas;

`token.php`

```
<?php
  class token{
    static public $tiempo_caducidad;

    static public function tiempo_caducidad($tiempo_caducidad){
      self::$tiempo_caducidad = $tiempo_caducidad;
    }
  }
```

`registrar_persona.php`

```
<?php
require('token.php'); //Te faltaban las comillas para el nombre de archivo...

class registrar_persona{
   function principal(){
     token::tiempo_caducidad(60*60);
   }

   //Te cree este método para que pruebes que funciona...
   public function getTiempoCaducidad(){
     return token::$tiempo_caducidad;
   }
}
$clase_registrar_persona = new registrar_persona();
$clase_registrar_persona->principal();
echo $clase_registrar_persona->getTiempoCaducidad();
```

Cuando tienes una clase `estatica` el concepto de `this` pasa a ser `self` dentro de la clase, para acceder a propiedades o metodos de una clase estatica se utiliza `self::$propierdad` o `self::metodo()`, puedes ampliar mas en esta respuesta.

[¿Para qué sirve Self y This en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/130249/para-qu%C3%A9-sirve-self-y-this-en-php)

Comment: es perfecto, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Se trata de un error de concepto de Orientacion a objetos.

Estas tratando de acceder, desde un metodo static, a una propiedad dinamica (de objeto). Esto no es posible, porque no se ha declarado en memoria la propiedad ANTES de llamarla desde del metodo. Esto solo podria hacerse si se ha declarado antes un objeto de tipo token con `new`.

Otra cosa seria que quisieras acceder desde un metodo de objeto, a una propiedad estatica. En ese caso si vas a poder, porque primero vas a crear el objeto, y ya estara disponible en memoria.

Para solucionar esto, define la propiedad de la clase token como `static`:

`private static $tiempo_caducidad;`

Con esto, tanto el metodo como la propiedad pasan a ser de clase, de tipo static, y por tanto puedes acceder desde un metodo static a dicha propiedad