# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function setAhorroUnidad()

Tags: funciones, php7, función-personalizada

¡Hola, muy buenas!
Estoy tratando de crearuna página programada orientada a objetos en PHP y en una de las clases me dice que no está definida esa función. El mensaje completo es:

**Fatal error**: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function setAhorroUnidad() in C:\xampp\htdocs\alg\Modelo\Objeto_producto.php:308 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\alg\Controlador\Insertar_Controlador.php(249): Objeto_Producto->setPrecioAnterior(40) #1 {main} thrown in **C:\xampp\htdocs\alg\Modelo\Objeto_producto.php** on line **308**

Es la única función que me da error. Os dejo la definición métodos referentes de la propiedad $AhorroUnidad:

```
//--------PROPIEDAD $AhorroUnidad DEL PRODUCTO ---------

// Obtener el AHORRO EN % POR UNIDAD si había un precio anterior
public function getAhorroUnidad() {
    return $this->AhorroUnidad;
}

// Calcular automáticamente el AHORRO POR UNIDAD si había un  precio anterior.
public function setAhorroUnidad($precio,$precioanterior) {
    $ahorro = $this->calcularAhorro($precio,$precioanterior);
    $this->AhorroUnidad = $ahorro;
}
```

Me he dado cuenta de que me pasa con las 2 funciones a las que llama  la  función setPrecioAnterior(). Os la comparto:

```
//--------PROPIEDAD $PrecioAnterior DEL PRODUCTO ---------

// Obtener el PRECIO ANTERIOR del producto
public function getPrecioAnterior() {
    return $this->PrecioAnterior;
}

// Darle un PRECIO ANTERIOR al producto
public function setPrecioAnterior($precioanterior) {

    $this->PrecioAnterior = $precioanterior;

    // Establece el ahorro por unidad en porcentaje, en relación del precio anterior al acutal.
    setAhorroUnidad($this->getPrecio,$this->PrecioAnterior);

    // Establece el ahorro por unidad en €uros, en relación del precio anterior al acutal.
    setAhorroEurosUnidad($this->Precio,$this->PrecioAnterior);
}
```

Están llamadas bien escritas desde el controlador. Lo sé porque el editor de texto que uso me dice en qué página o páginas se está llamando a dicha función y en qué línea exactamente y en qué archivo y linea exacta está definida.

Finalmente os dejo el if desde el controlador que llama a la función setPrecioAnterior()

```
if((floatval($_POST["PrecioAnterior"]) > 0) && (floatval($_POST["Precio"]) < floatval($_POST["PrecioAnterior"]))) {
    $producto->setPrecioAnterior(floatval($_POST["PrecioAnterior"]));
    echo "<br>El Precio anterior es: " . $producto->getPrecio5U() . "<br>";
} elseif((floatval($_POST["PrecioAnterior"]) > 0) && (floatval($_POST["Precio"]) >= (floatval($_POST["PrecioAnterior"])))) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("No PUEDES poner un PRECIO ANTERIOR más bajo que el PRECIO de venta.");
            window.location="../Vista/prueba_editor.html";
        </script>';
} elseif((floatval($_POST["PrecioAnterior"]) > 0) && (floatval($_POST["Precio"]) == 0)) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("No PUEDES poner un PRECIO ANTERIOR sin haber rellenado el PRECIO.");
            window.location="../Vista/prueba_editor.html";
        </script>';
}
```

El resto de funciones derivadas de alguna otra llamada desde el controlador no me da fallo.
Espero haber sido suficientemente claro y no haber escrito demasiado.

Comment: En el segundo bloque de código te falta poner `$this` delante de los métodos: `$this->setAhorroUnidad($this->getPrecio,$this->PrecioAnterior);` y `$this->setAhorroEurosUnidad($this->Precio,$this->PrecioAnterior);`

Comment: ¡Hola! ¡Genial! Era el dichoso $this... me estaba volviendo loco... ¡Infinitas gracias! :) Por cierto... ¿Cómo le doy como aceptada a tu respuesta, A. Cedano? Sólo veo la opción de reportar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando estás en el ámbito de un objeto debes usar `$this` para llamar los métodos y propiedades de dicho objeto **que no sean estáticos**, y `self` para llamar los métodos o propiedades del mismo que sean estáticos.

De hecho, ya en las propiedades se ve que usas `$this`, pero te falta usarlo también para llamar a  los métodos `setAhorroUnidad()`  y  `setAhorroEurosUnidad()`

```
public function setPrecioAnterior($precioanterior) {

    $this->PrecioAnterior = $precioanterior;

    // Establece el ahorro por unidad en porcentaje, en relación del precio anterior al acutal.
    $this->setAhorroUnidad($this->getPrecio,$this->PrecioAnterior);

    // Establece el ahorro por unidad en €uros, en relación del precio anterior al acutal.
    $this->setAhorroEurosUnidad($this->Precio,$this->PrecioAnterior);
}
```

Para más detalles consulta:

1. El [**Clases y objetos** en el *Manual de PHP*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.basic.php)
2. [**Propiedades** en el *Manual de PHP*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.properties.php)
3. [¿Para qué sirve Self y This en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/130249/29967)
4. [Pregunta sobre `self` y `$this` en Stackoverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/151976/5587982)

Comment: ¡Muchasgracias  porlaaclaración sobre el this y el self!