# variable undefined pero funciona - PHP

Tags: php

estoy creando una conexión  con POO, y me salta que la variable $conn esta indefinida , pero luego el programa ( que lo único que hace es un registro a la base de datos) funciona correctamente.

```
  class Conexion{      

protected $conn;
      public function Conexion(){


         try{
            $this->$conn = new mysqli(HOST,USUARIO,PASSWORD,DB);
            $this->$conn->set_charset(CHARSET);
         } 
         catch(EXCEPTION $e){
            echo $e;  
         }

      }
}
```

Comment: Cambia `$this->$conn` por `$this->conn`

Comment: y una pregunta, eso por que es asi? Me ha funcionado gracias, pero no lo entiendo

Comment: Fernando, en el [enlace 2](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.properties.php), al final de [la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/338621/29967), encontrarás la explicación del Manual de PHP: «*Dentro de los métodos de una clase, se puede acceder a las propiedades no estáticas utilizando `->` (el operador de objeto): `$this->propiedad` (donde propiedad es el nombre de la propiedad). A las propiedades estáticas se puede acceder utilizando `::` (doble dos puntos): `self::$propiedad`*» Si observas, en las propiedades estáticas si se usa `$` para la propiedad, precedido de `self`.

Comment: muchas gracias!